# SQL select group by show counts with 0

Tags: sql, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

good day

I have a SQL table
`Flights(id, departure_datetime, terminal_id)`

I need to perform a SQL request to pull data in a format like

```
+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
| termilal_id | hour(departure_datetime)| count(*) |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
|           1 |                       0 |        1 |
|           1 |                       1 |        2 |
|           1 |                       4 |        4 |
...
|           3 |                      23 |        1 |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

my current SQL is

```
SELECT terminal_id, hour(departure_datetime), count(*) 
FROM airpot_terminals
WHERE date(departure_datetime) = CURRENT_DATE()-1 
GROUP BY terminal_id, hour(departure_datetime) 
ORDER BY terminal_id, hour(departure_datetime)
```

everything seems ok,
but I get 50-60 results instead of 72 (3 terminals by 24 hours).

how can I show rows with even 0 records in select?

Comment: I'd guess you have some hours without any departures. Outer join a tally table to get those hours as well.

Comment: make sure that you have all the terminal_id and hour values in the table that you are running. as jarlh said, it maybe that you may have some hours without any departure

Comment: this is the point - i guess i need to create a temp table `termilal_id x 24 hours` and map all results to the temp table;